# C# WebClient UploadStringAsync takes time to execute sometime

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient

I have a rather confusing problem at hand. Trying to post some JSON to some .php files on a remote server.

The code is the following:

```
wc = new WebClient();
Uri urlToRequest = new Uri(webserviceUrl + url);

wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadDataCompleted);
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");

var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

wc.UploadStringAsync(urlToRequest, json);

Console.WriteLine("Async time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I am posting to 2 php files on the same server, the same JSON (expecting different results).

When I post to the first file I get this in the console:

```
Async time: 2576
```

When I post to the other I get this in the console:

```
Async time: 0
```

The JSON I am sending is a really simple `{"user":"bob","action":"get"}`

When debugging and I put a breakpoint for example at `wc = new WebClient();` and just go Step Over line by line, on the first call the Step Over hangs at `UploadStringAsync` for 2-3 seconds but on the second call it just jumps over it (as it should).

The .php files are on the same server.
Any ideas why is the same call behaves differently in 2 calls, and shouldn't `UploadStringAsync` be async in all cases?

Comment: Are you sure that the server doesn't cache the result the second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up on the subject i got to some conclusions:
from this answer [Why does WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync() block ? - new async API/syntax/CTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057926/why-does-webclient-downloadstringtaskasync-block-new-async-api-syntax-ctp/4876699#4876699)

```
wc.Proxy = null;
```

this solves the problem and the first request is now down to 10-15ms which is acceptable.
The small delay in the first request seems to be a DNS resolve issue, which still runs synchronously according to this:
[C# async methods still hang UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726131/c-sharp-async-methods-still-hang-ui/6726335#6726335)